# Singly Linked List Creation in C

Tags: c

I want to create a singly linked list using C. Why is this piece of code not working? The code is given below.  I am using CodeBlocks for running this which is an opensource compiler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
  int info;
  struct node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void create()
{
  struct node *ptr;
  int i,n;
  printf("Enter the number of nodes");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data.");
    scanf("%d",&ptr->info);
    ptr=ptr->next;
    if(first==NULL)
    {first=ptr;}
  }
  ptr->next=NULL;
}
void main()
{
  create();

}
```

Comment: You should probably add the error you get. "Not working" is not enough for SO.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ptr=ptr->next;` in your loop, you loose `ptr` and then you point to garbage because `next` is not yet initialized. So first link `ptr` into the list and then go to `next`.

Doing that I leave for you as excercise.